# How to set and retrieve cookies in Grails?

Tags: grails, cookies

I'm trying to use a cookie in a Grails application with no success. In particular, in the show() method of a test suite controller, I want to set a cookie to be the most recent test suite shown; that is, the value of params.id as made available to the show() method. Then, in the list() method, I want to provide a shortcut to showing the most recent test suite (the value I'm trying to set with a cookie).

However, the cookie I set (named "tcCookie") is visible only in the show() method - not in the list() method. Here's the code:

in show():

```
request.cookies.each { println "show: cookie ${it.name} <${it.value}>" }
```

in list():

```
request.cookies.each { println "list: cookie ${it.name} <${it.value}>" }
```

I set the cookie in the show() method by:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie( "tcCookie", params.id )
cookie.maxAge = 315360000000L
response.addCookie( cookie )
```

When I go back and forth between the list and show views (after show() with params.id = 277) I get:

```
show: cookie tcCookie <277>
show: cookie JSESSIONID <9DEBFB40F78B5E24A92C750157342069>
list: cookie JSESSIONID <9DEBFB40F78B5E24A92C750157342069>
show: cookie tcCookie <277>
show: cookie JSESSIONID <9DEBFB40F78B5E24A92C750157342069>
list: cookie JSESSIONID <9DEBFB40F78B5E24A92C750157342069>
```

which appears to me to indicate that the cookie "tcCookie" is visible only in the show() method, which is useless to me. I need to set it so that it's visible in other methods.

Additionally the cookie tcCookie survives across multiple sessions - as I would expect - but still is visible only in the show() method.

Maybe my understanding of cookies is wrong, but I'm still stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Additionally, there must be hundreds of other cookies set in the browser, none of which are visible using the code I've used, so is there some way to get to the other cookies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is a side effect of setting the cookie without explicitly setting the path.  Assuming the Grails application's name is "app" it would be accessed by

```
http://hostname.com/app
```

This will cause the cookie JSESSIONID to be set as `/app/JSESSIONID` which will be visible anywhere in the application.  Since the application's name is available within the application as `grailsApplication.metadata['app.name']` determining the actual value of `app` can be made automatic.

However, in an individual view, for example the `list` view in the `xxx_domain` object, accessed as

```
http://hostname.com/app/xxx_domain/list
```

setting a cookie with the code

```
def newCookie = new Cookie( "myCookie", "cookieValue" )
response.addCookie newCookie
```

will set the path of `newCookie` to `/app/xxx_domain/list/` where it will be visible only in the `list()` method and view.  In order for that cookie to be visible anywhere in the application, the path must be set as shown in the above answer, but not to `/`, rather to `/app` as in

```
def newCookie = new Cookie( "myCookie", "cookieValue" )
newCookie.path = "/${grailsApplication.metadata['app.name']}/"
response.addCookie newCookie
```

Comment: are you know how to delete cookie? not set `maxAge` to `0`>

Answer (score 4):

or you can read the basic Java doc and use plain `response` and `request` objects to do that:

```
Cookie homeCookie = new Cookie( 'home', 'name' )
homeCookie.path = '/'
homeCookie.maxAge = 0
response.addCookie homeCookie
```

and

```
String home = request.cookies.find{ 'home' == it.name }?.value
```

Comment: No, it makes no difference.  I still cannot see the cookie outside of the show() method.  The only difference in the above code and the original is setting the maxAge value to zero and the path to slash, neither of which make a difference in visibility.

Comment: make `request.cookies.each { println "list: cookie ${it.properties}>" }` to see more

Comment: Still no difference.  The JSESSIONID cookie is visible in both show() and list() but the cookie I set and care about is visible only in show().  If anyone has actually used cookies in multiple views in Grails, please show me how it's possible because reading documentation and asking questions of users has come up with no suggestion of why there is a difference in visibility or, more importantly, how to make a cookie visible in a method other than the one in which it was set.

Comment: can you see your cookie in the browser's options?

Comment: Yes - and that points out the problem.  Indeed, the path is being set for the cookie, but making the path "/" as you suggested doesn't get the job done.  I will answer my own question more fully as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use this plugin : [Cookie Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cookie)

The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/stokito/grails-cookie)

The next code show you how to set a cookie:

```
cookieService.setCookie('username', 'cookieUser123')
```

And here, how to get the value inside your cookie:

```
cookieService.get('username')
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

For your last question, I think you can only access cookie(s) from your domain.